# React Native Expo Autologin Functionality

Tags: react-native, webview, expo, navigation-drawer, expo-router

_layout.js

```
import { GestureHandlerRootView } from "react-native-gesture-handler"
import { Drawer } from "expo-router/drawer"

export default function Layout() {
  return (
    <GestureHandlerRootView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Drawer>
        <Drawer.Screen
          name="index" // This is the name of the page and must match the url from root
          options={{
            drawerLabel: "Home",
            title: "",
          }}
        />
        <Drawer.Screen
          name="hackernews" // This is the name of the page and must match the url from root
          options={{
            drawerLabel: "HackerNews",
            title: "",
          }}
        />
        <Drawer.Screen
          name="more" // This is the name of the page and must match the url from root
          options={{
            drawerLabel: "More",
            title: "",
          }}
        />
        <Drawer.Screen
          name="securestore" // This is the name of the page and must match the url from root
          options={{
            drawerLabel: "secureStore",
            title: "",
          }}
        />
      </Drawer>
    </GestureHandlerRootView>
  )
}
```

hackernews.js

```
import { React } from "react"
import { StyleSheet } from "react-native"
import { WebView } from "react-native-webview"

export default function Page() {
  return (
    <WebView
      style={styles.container}
      source={{ uri: "https://news.ycombinator.com/login" }}
      injectedJavaScriptBeforeContentLoaded={`
      document.getElementsByName("acct")[0].value="testLogin"
      document.getElementsByName("pw")[0].value="testPassword"
      document.getElementsByTagName("input")[2].click()
      `}
    />
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
})
```

Hi I want to build autologin functionality for some websites using expo's WebView. I have two problems right now. 1. When I first time go to hackernews from my drawer I automatically login as planned, but when I manually log out and try to change drawer tab and go back I do not login again. 2. When I click on some link on hackernews I have no possibility of going back to hackernews main page. Below code including layout and hackernews WebView component.